# Sample code for uploading and retrieving images to and from MySql server using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, blob

How to upload and retrieve images to and from MySql database using PHP. I need sample code to convert images into binary equivalent and vice versa so that they can be stored and retrieved to and from MySql database in the BLOB format. I tried my best online but I couldn't. Any help will highly be appreciated.

Comment: Way too broad a question, and storing/retrieving images in DB has been asked/answered on this site way too many times.

Comment: Please use Google first before posting a question on here and sitting back waiting for other people to fabricate the code for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this links they may help u to get started

[storing images in mysql](http://www.phpriot.com/articles/storing-images-in-mysql)

and

[How to Store images in mysql database with php](http://mrarrowhead.com/index.php?page=store_images_mysql_php.php)

Answer (score 0):

```sql
CREATE TABLE `pix` 
  ( 
     `pic_id`   INT(11) NOT NULL auto_increment, 
     `pic_name` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, 
     `pic_data` LONGBLOB NOT NULL, 
     PRIMARY KEY (`pic_id`) 
  ) 
engine=innodb 
DEFAULT charset=latin1;
```

Get 2 php files:- Image.php, showImage.php.

Set Connection parameters accordingly.

```php
/* Image.php*/

<?php

    $con = mysql_connect("127.0.0.1:3306", "root", "");

    if (!$con) {
        die("Could not connect: " . mysql_error());
    }

    $DB = mysql_select_db("test", $con);
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["uploadedfile"]["tmp_name"], "latest.img");
    $instr = fopen("latest.img","rb");
    $image = addslashes(fread(fopen("latest.img","r"),filesize("latest.img")));
    mysql_query ("insert into pix (pic_name, pic_data) values ("myImage", "'.$image.'");");

?>
<html>
    <form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">

        <img src=showImage.php?gim=1 width=500 height=150 alt="hell">

        <br>
        <hr>

        <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="100000" /> Choose a file to upload(
        <100 KB): <input name="uploadedfile" type="file" />
        <br/>

        <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit" />    
    </form>
<html>
/*showImage.php*/

<?php

    $con = mysql_connect("127.0.0.1:3306", "root", "");

    if (!$con) {
        die(“Could not connect: ” . mysql_error());
    }

    $DB = mysql_select_db("test", $con);
    $res = @mysql_query("select * from pix order by pic_id desc limit 1");

    if ($row = @mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {

        $title = htmlspecialchars($row[pic_name]);
        $bytes = $row[pic_data];

    }

    header("Content-type: image/jpg");
    print $bytes;
    mysql_close();
?>
```